# UPDATED: D3 won't draw chart data on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have an html form and d3 chart. The idea is that each checkbox in the form represents a bar on the graph. Each bar's visibility is set to hidden until someone selects options from the form and the chart function reveals the bars that each checked checkbox represents.

However, I also want some bars to pre-load based on the form's pre-selected check boxes (marked checked on load).

The problem is that the chart only displays the bars after a checkbox has been changed.

It will not show the pre-selected data on load. This is despite having check boxes pre-selected and running the exact same function that the checkboxes call when changed (it works when a user makes a change but not on load)

Why isn't the function that reveals the bars working on load? Why does it only work when the checkbox is changed after load?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m9md5fhk/)

HTML

```
  <form class="form" action="">
      <div class="buildOptions">
        <div class="instructions">Select ingredients:</div>
          <div class="selection">
            <input class="ingredientBox" type="checkbox" name="ingredient" value="bars1" onclick="showBars()" checked="checked"> <span class="ingredientBoxText"style="border-color:#bf812d;">bar 1</span>
          </div>

         </div>
         </form>
```

JS

```
var activeData =[];
 function showBars(){
      // variables //


      //Get all lines from chart and place in an array
      var bars = []
      //Grab all checkbox selections
      var selected = document.getElementsByName("ingredient");

      //// Reset chart if needed ////

      //Empty the activeData variable
      activeData=[];

        //loop through all hte lines and make them hidden
      for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        bars[i].style.visibility="hidden";
      }

      /// Use input to draw chart ///

      //loop through check box values
      for (var i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
        //If a checkbox is checked add the value to the activeData array
        if (selected[i].checked){
          activeData.push(selected[i].value)
          //take the name of the active checkbox and edit it to coincide with id of lines
          var newId = selected[i].value.replace('1','');
          //Use line id to to make appropriate line visible
          var activeBar =document.getElementById(newId)
          activeBar.style.visibility="visible"
        }
      }
    }

function drawChart(){
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */
var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));
// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];
// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });
var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("class", "bars")
//.attr("id", dataset[0][0])
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });
// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });
// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);
tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
}
drawChart();
showBars();
```

CSS

```
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
  }

  path.domain {
    stroke: none;
  }

  .y .tick line {
    stroke: #ddd;
  }
.bars{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/tktUweOyUxTAOXYJ6BQf?p=preview) which shows the data on load. I think the css property .bars - overwrites the bars getting drawn.So remove that property.

```
.bars{
            visibility:hidden;
        }
```

I rewrite showBars function to show bars and hide bars. Also when you look at your fiddle link it shows error lines is not defined. So you may want to add lines data.

```
    function showBars() {
         // variables //
        var selected = document.getElementsByName("ingredient");
      for (var i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
      //If a checkbox is checked add the value to the activeData array
      if (selected[i].checked === false){
         d3.selectAll(".cost").style("visibility","hidden");
      }

      if(selected[i].checked === true) {
          d3.selectAll(".cost").style("visibility","visible");

      }
}
```